# flutter ListView.builder is showing blank or empty data sometimes

Tags: flutter, listview, indexing

I have List of 250 `Products` of 10 different categories. `Product` structure is below

```
class Product {
  final int productId;
  final int categoryId;
  final String nameEn;
  final String descriptionEn;

  Product(
      {this.productId,
      this.categoryId,
      this.nameEn,
      this.descriptionEn
      });
}
```

Depending on selected category, I like to show Product list using `ListView.builder`. It shows proper list of `Product` at beginning for any selected category. After using sometime, if I select category 3 or category 1, it shows empty list. Then I debugPrint to find where goes wrong. Everything looks fine except `index` of `itemBuilder: (BuildContext _, int index)` value. It doesn't iterate from 0, instead of it iterate from 15 or 20 or 50 or sometimes 120. if `index` starts from 30 when I select category 1, then I get empty list because category 1 products are 0-25 index of `Product` list.
below is my listView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.products.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext _, int index) {
          debugPrint('index is = $index');
          var categoryId = widget.products[index].categoryId;
          if (categoryId == selectedCategory) {
            int cartProductQty = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < widget.cartProducts.length; i++) {
              if (widget.products[index].productId ==
                  widget.cartProducts[i].cartProductId) {
                cartProductQty = widget.cartProducts[i].cartProductQty;
              }
            }
            return SingleProduct(
              productId: widget.products[index].productId,
              productName: widget.products[index].nameBn,
              productCategory: widget.products[index].categoryId,
              cartProductQty: cartProductQty,
            );
          } else {
            return DoNothing();
          }
        },
      );
```

How can I solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Return a list item only if its category id matches selected category id

```html
 ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.products.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext _, int index) {
              var categoryId = widget.products[index].categoryId;          
              return selectedCategory == categoryId ?:Container();
              SingleProduct(
                  productId: widget.products[index].productId,
                  productName: widget.products[index].nameBn,
                  productCategory: widget.products[index].categoryId,
                  cartProductQty: cartProductQty,
                ):Container();
            },
          );
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek singh, unfortunately this is not the solution. I am returning list of products when selected category matches with product category. The problem arises when I select category1 or 2 or 3 but index iterate from 60 or higher, It should start from 0, otherwise how can i get previous data.

Comment: 1: Create a variable of type List<Product>  2:Create a function which takes selected Id as an argument 3: Polulate the List<Product> with selected category only 4: call setState inside this function 5: give this List<Product> in ListView.builder.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek singh, it helps but it creates another problem.  Every time I click / select a category, new variable populate Product of that selected category and ListView generates from that variable. Now If I tap favorite button of a product, it goes automatically favorite to another category of same index product.

Comment: @HumayunKabir add first line as whateverYourListNameIs.clear() it will remove all the items which were previously added and will populate the list with the desired items.

Comment: @ Abhishek singh, I have done it. I will tell details how I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it solved.

Instead of sending all items into `ListView.builder`, I sent those item which category matches with selected category.